# Why Laravel error messages are not correct in my app ? = ex: validation.min.string

Tags: laravel, authentication, breeze

I have a weird problem today with my laravel app :
Validation error messages are not the same as usual : for example "password must be at least 8 caracters".
Instead of this, the error message displays "validation.min.string".

I never had this sort of problems, and don't understand what happen.

I tried adding messages() method in the LoginRequest (I am using Breeze for authentification) :

```
class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
 
 
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'email.required' => 'Email is required',
        'email.email' => 'Email is invalid',
        'password.required' => 'Password is required',
        'password.min:6' => 'Password must be at least 6 characters',
    ];
}

/**
 * Attempt to authenticate the request's credentials.
 *
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}

/**
 * Ensure the login request is not rate limited.
 *
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
public function ensureIsNotRateLimited()
{
    if (! RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($this->throttleKey(), 5)) {
        return;
    }

    event(new Lockout($this));

    $seconds = RateLimiter::availableIn($this->throttleKey());

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'email' => trans('auth.throttle', [
            'seconds' => $seconds,
            'minutes' => ceil($seconds / 60),
        ]),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Get the rate limiting throttle key for the request.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function throttleKey()
{
    return Str::lower($this->input('email')).'|'.$this->ip();
}
}
```

Of course I display the messages in my view, using blade directives :

```
@error('email')
       <span class="validation-error">{{ $message }}</span>
@enderror
@error('password')
       <span class="validation-error">{{ $message }}</span>
@enderror
```

But nothing more happens... just the same unfriendly message "validation.min.string" or "auth.failed" or something like this depending the error.

Authentication works well, it's just a problem with those error messages.

I had the same problem with an other form and i solved it creating a Request with rules and messages methods.
This time it doesn't work.

Anyone could help me to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is in the custom validation message
this index `password.min:6` need to change to `password.min`

for more info please check [Laravel custom error message](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages)

Comment: Thanks again, but I am having the same problem with the register part. I didn't edit nothing, just let the breeze code. i didn't edit any additionnal rule or personalized error message; but breeze displays the same message as I mentionned : 'validation.email' or 'validation.min.string' and not user friendly message as as usual. I really don't know from where comes this problem

Comment: mention its rules , & custom messages , please

Comment: $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
            
        ]);

Comment: and no messages

Comment: seems good , 
make sure that this file exists  `lang/en/validation.php`

Comment: Yes ! thank you so much, that was the problem : I changed the locale to 'fr' and of course i didn't have the french translations in my lang directory. You made my day, thank you again Omar

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this code:

```
public function messages(): array
{
    return [
        'email.required' => 'Email is required',
        'email.email' => 'Email is invalid',
        'password.required' => 'Password is required',
        'password.min' => 'Password must be at least 6 characters',
    ];
}
```